# Why are some page/application methods in EwfPage and others in EwfUiStatics?

Tags: c#, enterprise-web-library

I've been using EWL for some time now and I feel as though there is an inconsistency. Some actions, like adding a status message is done via the `EwfPage` instance and others such as adding a page-level Action is done via `EwfUiStatics`.

Why aren't all of these similar methods in one place or another? One guess I have is that possibly the methods that are on `EwfPage` require the instance (and the others are static). But that reason would be refuted by the fact that the property `EwfPage.Instance` exists, always giving you a static handle on those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EwfPage` members can be used on all pages whereas `EwfUiStatics` members should only be used on Enterprise Web Framework User Interface (EWF UI) pages.